# I'm looking for the Windows-10 driver for the Atmel bootloader used in the Atmel UC3-A3 Xplained evaluation kit

Tags: driver, programming, atmel, avr32

I have a couple of Atmel boards called Atmel UC3-A3 Xplained
evaluation kit, and am trying to use them in a project.

I want to use the bootloader, which is apparently pre-installed on the AVR32 chip, to load code I develop in Atmel Studio running under Windows-10.

I'm using the Atmel document "Atmel AVR32930: UC3-A3 Xplained Getting
Started Guide" which is on the Microchip www site: https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/Appnotes/doc32163.pdf

The first line of the document is:
Easy to reprogram with just a USB cable and a preprogrammed boot loader

- which is exactly what I'm trying to do.

Page 2 says:
When connecting the UC3-A3 Xplained board to a PC, the operating system will request a driver file for installing the serial communication driver. This driver file is available in the zip file associated with this document. The driver file supports both
the 32- and the 64-bit versions of Windows® XP and Windows 7. Driver installs are not necessary on Linux® operating systems.

Four problems:

1. I can't find any zip file associated with this document.
2. No request for driver file occurs when I connect the board.
3. I'm running Windows-10. Not XP or 7.
4. Atmel Studio can't see the board.

I've searched many places for the correct driver - no luck.

Any suggestions?

I'm wondering whether Microchip has stopped supporting this board, even though they still offer them for sale.

Comment: That sounds like a question for Microchip. Have you tried contacting them? Most of the avr32 product line is obsolete. I’d suggest looking at a different family.